# Phonegap Developer App (iOS) doesn't load external images

Tags: android, ios, iphone, cordova

I'm trying to render images in my application deploying in [Phonegap Developer App](https://itunes.apple.com/br/app/phonegap-developer/id843536693?mt=8) for iOS, I already updated the config.xml with the whitelist domain access:

```
<access origin="*" />
<access uri="*" subdomains="false" />
```

HTML snippet:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/myphoto.jpg">
```

If I build using **Android simulator** (`phonegap build android`), it works fine, all images loaded, in other hand at **Phonegap Developer iOS App** all images appears blank spots, also It's impossible to track any BUGs because it doesn't show any issues at console log.

Obs: I'm debugging the application running the command: `phonegap app` and opening the URL http://mylocalip:3000/

I have no idea what's wrong with my application or if this is a truly Phonegap Developer App BUG.

PLS HELP!

Comment: When you run in iOS simulator, try safari developer tools. check image src in inspect element.

Comment: The developer doesn't make use of your `config.xml` it only renders the HTML/CSS/JS of your project from a remote location. My guess is that the `config.xml` used to compile the app doesn't allow for this.